# Rename [elastic-ip] to [amazon-elastic-ip]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We did it for all the amazon-related products but it looks like this one fell true the cracks:

[image: Amazon-Tags]

[elastic-ip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/elastic-ip) should be renamed to [amazon-elastic-ip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-elastic-ip).

Answer (score 2):

This retagging has been completed.